# Python3 alternative of increment for expressions

Tags: python, python-3.5, increment

Imagine, I have `index = 0`, `hash = '06123gfhtg75677687fgfg4'` and I want to process expression like `hash[i++]`. How to do this in Python3 ?

Notice, I need `index = 1` after this expression. I need one-line expression, if possible.

Expected usage below:

```
enc = bytes(enc % len(session_key))
x = bytes(data[i] ^ session_key[enc++]) + ej)
data[i] = ej = x
```

Comment: `hash[i]` and then in the next line `i += 1`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I need one-line expression, if possible

Comment: Could you detail the expected inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: "I need one-line expression, if possible" - why do you think you need this?

Comment: @kull1n I ve updated the question

Comment: @user2357112 see code example in updated question

Comment: what is enc++ supposed to be doing?

Comment: Your example doesn't need to hide the update inside the `x =` line. You can do `enc += 1` on the next line, and you'll get cleaner, more understandable code.

Comment: @kull1n this is part of encryption algorithm

Comment: @user2357112 got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools.count()` object, with `next` to give the current value and increment it. That would emulate `++` postfix C/C++ operator properly.

Example:

```
import itertools

c = itertools.count()  # starts at 0, but can be passed a start value as argument

s = 'abc'
print(s[next(c)])
print(s[next(c)])
print(s[next(c)])
```

prints a,b,c in sequence.